# Move focus to text box when editing favourite tags

Tags: bug, design

I'm not sure whether this is a problem with the new design or if it was there in the old one, but it's there. If I click on the `edit` button on the Favorite Tags sidebar, it brings up a text box and an `Add` button, as well as deletesy `x`s on the tags that are already there.

[image]

It doesn't however, move the focus to the text box, and there's no reason why it shouldn't. I either want to delete tags, which I can only do with the mouse, or I want to get typing some new ones.

Minor change but still worth it.